# Generate Google login page url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

My current web page using a google sign in button, but is it possible to generate a url for google login since I do not want to store the credential or pass the credentials in the frontend server.

I searched through the solutions, and mostly is create a button on frontend and redirect to google login page from frontend directly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by generate the URL. The URL that your clients will use does not change after you create the OAuth Client. The URL is based on a couple of known parameters such as Client ID and Redirect URI, but why go thru the extra effort? Edit your question to clarify the problem.